# select an item in spinner toggle text view showing relevant data in database

Tags: android, sqlite, textview, spinner

My title might not be good, i'll explain it more detail here.
Current i have a spinner populated from database. What i wanted to do now is when i selected one of the item in the spinner, i will have a text view to show the data in the same database same row just different column. 
For example, my database currently have the primary key _id, title, and description. The drop down list will show the title. After a title is selected, the TextView shall fetch the description from the database and show it.
I'm still quite new to android development and have no idea how to achieve this. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. set the row id's of the entries inside the spinner to the _id from the query in your SpinnerAdapter (this should happen automatically if you use a SimpleCursorAdapter)
2. in  `onItemSelected (Spinner parent, View view, int position, long id)` use the id to query the db and populate the TextView accordingly.